# Using BlueJ, I can 'Pop' & 'Push' but can't 'Top'?

Tags: java

(student Software Developer here!)

We (our class) have recently started a new java topic using BlueJ. This is brand new to me but I am enjoying and half understanding it so far.

We have to create a vertically stacked array, using a menu that has 5 options:
1- Push
2- Pop
3- Top
4- Display
5- Quit

I have managed to code everything except for 'Top' (display the integer at the top of the stack/array)

My lecturer has given us this hint "You could 'Pop' then 'Push' to be able to 'Top'" but I am not too sure how to get it to work?

This is my code for the menu:

```
public static void main()
    {
        int option;
        Array a = new Array();
        String []menuitems = {"1 - Push","2 - Pop","3 - Top","4 - Display","5 - Quit"};            
        Menu m = new Menu(menuitems,5);

        a.add(4);a.add(2);a.add(28);a.add(15);

        do
        {
            clrscr();
            option = m.showMenu();
            if ( option == 1 )                                
                doPush(a);   
            if ( option == 2 )                                
                doPop(a);   
            if ( option == 3 )                                
                doTop(a);   
            if ( option == 4 )                
            {                    
                a.display();
                pressKey();
            }
        }
        while ( option != 5 );
        System.out.println("Done - You Can Now Close");
    }
```

This is my code for Push:

```
public static void doPush(Array a)
    {
        if ( a.isFull() )
                {
                    System.out.print("\nArray Full!");                        
                }
                else {
                    int item;
                    System.out.print("Enter number to push: ");
                    item = Genio.getInteger();

                    if ( a.addToFront(item) == false)
                        System.out.print("\nArray Is Full!");
                    System.out.print("\nArray with new value: \n");
                    a.display();
                }
                pressKey();
    }
```

This is my code for Pop:

```
public static void doPop(Array a)
    {
        if ( a.isEmpty() ) {
            System.out.println("\nArray is Empty!");
            pressKey();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int item;
            item = Genio.getInteger();
            System.out.println("\nArray popped!");
        }


                pressKey();
    }
```

Comment: Just pop the element, return it, and then push it back onto the data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest defining the `pop()` and `push()` methods on the `Array` class itself. Then you can define `top()` as follows:

```
public int top() {
    int topValue = pop();
    push(topValue);
    return topValue;
}
```

i.e. you pop it off the stack keep a note of the value and then push it back on the stack. It's not a super-efficient implementation, but if that's his hint then I'd do it like that.

I would also suggest using exceptions, rather than `System.out.println()` for error conditions, and defining a specific class for the `Stack` that *uses* the Array:

```
public class Stack {

    private Array array = new Array();

    public int push(int item) {
        if (!array.addToFront(item)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is full");
        }
        /* TODO: It would be better (more idiomatic) for the Array.addToFront()
         * method threw this exception rather than returning a boolean.
         */ 
    }

    public int pop() {
        assertStackNotEmpty();

        // TODO: Remove the item from the front of the array
        //       and shuffle everything along

        return item;
    }

    public int peek() {
        assertStackNotEmpty();
        return array.get(0);
    }

    /**
     * Lecturer's suggested implementation of peek()
     */
    public int top() {
        int item = pop();
        push(item);
        return item;
    }

    private void assertStackNotEmpty() {
       if (array.isEmpty()) {
           throw new EmptyStackException("Stack is empty");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was unsure about that. What is the difference/benefit if that? Just literally cut them into the class?

Comment: The point is to put the logic to do with pushing/popping into the object that is most suited to hold it (the one that has the data).

Comment: There is a JDK [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class and its interface is similar to what I'm suggesting.

Comment: Isn't top just pointing to the first element? Why pop and push it, just return Array[0] ?

Comment: One reason would be to avoid duplicating any error-handling you might do for an empty stack.

Comment: Using a Stack interface as a guide though, top() is comparable to peek(), and you do not remove the element to view it in an implementation of a Stack.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree, it's a poor implementation. I was just trying to  think of a reason the lecturer might have suggested it.

Comment: How does peek look? Despite what my lecturer said, he does welcome us implementing things that we have sourced ourselves so if it works then it would be fine by him.